# Laravel package joelbutcher / socialstream - how to add Socialite Providers

Tags: laravel

In the README for [joelbutcher / socialstream](https://github.com/joelbutcher/socialstream#socialite-providers) it says:

> You will then need to alter the [...] provider condition:
>
> - Connected Account component
> - Socialstream Providers component

This leads me to believe that I need to alter `/vendor/joelbutcher/socialstream/src/Providers.php` - which seems not to be published. I search my codebase (having run `artisan publish --all`) for `hasBitbucketSupport` and the only place that the string is found is as above.

Can you confirm if this is a bug? Can you give me a step by step of how to add new Socialite Providers for this package?

I am keen to be able to provide Microsoft 365 & Apple login options.

Comment: they are talking about adjusting the components (views)  https://github.com/joelbutcher/socialstream/tree/3.x/stubs/livewire/resources/views/components  which would have all been published when you ran the install command

Comment: I have to add the Provider to /config/socialstream.php. That is looking at /vendor/joelbutcher/socialstream/src/Providers.php for the class names of the providers I am adding.